# Convert JSON to GridView in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have the following JSON that I am looking to convert into a GridView. I have been able to successfully do this for a portion of the JSON. It seems to fail on the deposit and withdrawals section. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "51142254",
      "tp_id": "!XP4D49X0CD123628",
      "firstname": "Owner",
      "lastname": "Operator",
      "email": "",
      "phone": "",
      "enrolled": "1",
      "balance": 247.54,
      "fleet": "Test Express",
      "deposits": [
        {
          "id": "184022380",
          "date": "2016-02-17",
          "amount": "200.00",
          "transID": "135246",
          "memo": "Scheduled Deposit",
          "status": "Cleared"
        },
        {
          "id": "184022383",
          "date": "2016-02-25",
          "amount": "200.00",
          "transID": "246357",
          "memo": "Scheduled Deposit",
          "status": "Cleared"
        },
        {
          "id": "184022386",
          "date": "2016-03-02",
          "amount": "200.00",
          "transID": "975468",
          "memo": "Scheduled Deposit",
          "status": "Cleared"
        }
      ],
      "withdrawals": [
        {
          "id": "184026949",
          "date": "2016-03-09",
          "amount": "352.46",
          "transID": "395920",
          "memo": "Invoice\r\n\r\n100234",
          "status": "Cleared"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "51142326",
      "tp_id": "!XP4D49X7CD123612",
      "firstname": "Owner",
      "lastname": "Operator",
      "email": "",
      "phone": "",
      "enrolled": "1",
      "balance": 0,
      "fleet": "Test\r\nExpress",
      "deposits": [],
      "withdrawals": []
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the current code I use for GridView.

```
Dim UserList As List(Of api_Test_Deposit) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of api_Test_Deposit))(GetUrlString(searchType, searchValue))
Dim table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(GetUrlString(searchType, searchValue))
Return table
```

Comment: By "it seems to fail" what do you mean?  What is the error or behavior you observe?

Comment: it sees the Deposit and withdrawals properties but it does not grab any of the properties or values for deposits or withdrawals. basically like they do not exist in the JSON string